# Generating random colors jQuery not adding css

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a random color picker, I want div's having class color to be colored fully in the random generated hex color. I tried adding just 1 block (worked) and now I tried to add it to a foreach .color like shown below:

```
    $("#generateColors").click(function () {
        $('.color').each(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Pastel/PastelRGB',
                type: "Get",
                success: function (data) {
                    $(this).css({
                        "background-color": data.hex
                    });
                    //$("#color1p").text(data.hex);
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, err) {
                    LogError(err);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

My HTML looks like this

```
<div><input type="button" id="generateColors"/></div>
<div class="color" style="width:200px;height:200px;background-color:white;"></div>
<div class="color" style="width:200px;height:200px;background-color:white;"></div>
<div class="color" style="width:200px;height:200px;background-color:white;"></div>
<div class="color" style="width:200px;height:200px;background-color:white;"></div>
<div class="color" style="width:200px;height:200px;background-color:white;"></div>
<div class="color" style="width:200px;height:200px;background-color:white;"></div>
<div class="color" style="width:200px;height:200px;background-color:white;"></div>
<div class="color" style="width:200px;height:200px;background-color:white;"></div>
<div class="color" style="width:200px;height:200px;background-color:white;"></div>
<div class="color" style="width:200px;height:200px;background-color:white;"></div>
```

The css just doesn't apply to the div..

I am in a learning process of HTML JS and CSS, so any help would be great!

Greets, Mick

Comment: why don't you make a single ajax request that return an array (with length `$('.color').length`) of random colours and then call the each() to assign the colour?

Comment: Is using AJAX a requirement here? You can generate a random color entirely client-side.

Comment: There are at least two wrong things : 1) you're making _ten_ simultaneous ajax calls on _each_ click, 2) then you're assigning a color to `$(this)`, which is the ajax success function, not an HTML element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can define a simple function **getColor()** to generate a randome color:

> In this function we use an array of ASCII codes

```
function getColor(){
   var ascii = [48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70];
   var color = '#';
   while(color.length < 7){
      color += String.fromCharCode(ascii[Math.floor((Math.random() * 15) + 0)]);
   }
   return color;
}
```

Then you can use it in your jQuery code like this:

```
$(this).css({
   'color': getColor(), // Get a first color
   'background-color': getColor() // Get a 2nd color and different to the 1st one
});
```

Answer (score 3):

This can be done on the client side. Doing `'#' +Math.random().toString(16).substring(2, 8)` tends to work well. So change:

```
$(this).css({
    "background-color": data.hex
});
```

To:

```
$(this).css({
    "background-color": '#' + Math.random().toString(16).substring(2, 8)
});
```

[Basic example](http://jsfiddle.net/7bxst0gf/)

Answer (score 2):

`this` inside of `success` is not referencing your element, but referencing success scope

remember element in the variable and then use it instead of this

```
$("#generateColors").click(function () {
    $('.color').each(function () {
        var element = this

        $.ajax({
            url: '/Pastel/PastelRGB',
            type: "Get",
            success: function (data) {
                $(element).css({
                    "background-color": data.hex
                });
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, err) {
                LogError(err);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

or just use parameter of each

```
.each(function (index,element) { ...
```